# Signing in using FB connect fails in IE9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I'm working on a facebook app where the user has to sign in (using FB) to participate. 
This works fine on every browser except IE9, after the app tries to sign in, the user gets the error "this content cannot be displayed in a frame"

[image: IE9 doing it's thing]

If I check the properties of the iframe, I can see the URL is http://myfancyapp.com/auth/facebook/callback

The signing in process seems to work since I can open the app outside the iframe and I'm successfully logged in. So the problem seems to be IE9's security policy. After some searching I figured out it needed P3P tags, so I added some in my application_controller like this:

[image: p3p headers]

I've also tried adding X-Frame-Options but it doesn't made a difference. What else could I try?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Omniauth was redirecting the wrong way, it tried to put the absolute URL in the iframe. Since the absolute URL was from Facebook, it gave an error since facebook URL's are not allowed to be loaded in an iframe.

To fix this, I modified the Omniauth initializer (omniauth.rb) and specified the full host like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, ENV['APP_ID'], ENV['APP_SECRET'], scope: 'email', full_host:ENV['FULL_HOST_URL']
end
```

The full host is stored in a environment var like this

```
FULL_HOST_URL='//myapp.provider.com'
```